# Read ZIP file from cloud storage via the streaming library

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I need to read a zip file, located in the Google Storage Bucket, without unzipping using airflow. I am using a library called stream-unzip.

```
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip
import httpx


def zipped_chunks():
    # Iterable that yields the bytes of a zip file
    with httpx.stream('GET', "<google_bucket_file_path>") as r:
        yield from r.iter_bytes(chunk_size=65536)


for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks(), password=b'my-password'):
    # unzipped_chunks must be iterated to completion or UnfinishedIterationError will be raised
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        print(chunks)
```

The error which I got when I tried with above code is:

```
stream_unzip.TruncatedDataError
```

This zip file contains a text-file that have millions of lines. I need to stream these lines and get the data in each line on the fly. The airflow is deployed in the composer environment.

Please suggest a good solution for this.
Thank you

Comment: maybe yiu need `io.StringIO()` or `io.BytesIO()`  to create `file-like` object in memory.

Comment: what is the problem with your current code? If you get error then show FULL error message in question (not in comments)

Comment: @furas I have updated the error in the question.

Comment: @furas But we will get the file as blob. There is a method get_blob in google-cloud library for that.  Will it create any memory issue when we large zip files?

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391702/18265638)